# Why does the Azure SQL Server store and display numbers but not exchange them with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, decimal, numeric

| Column datatype | As seen in SSMS "edit top 200 rows" | As returned from a SELECT statement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| decimal(29, 26) | < Unable to read data > | -795.00000000000000000000000000 |
| decimal(29, 26) | -790.00000000000000000000000000 | -790.00000000000000000000000000 |
| decimal(38, 35) | < Unable to read data > | -790.00000000000000000000000000000000000 |

Sometimes SQL Server can store and display a negative number that it cannot pass along to another program. The size of the number and the precision/scale of the column play a role. For example (above), -790 works when the P/S is 29/26. But -795 won't work. And -790 won't work when the P/S is 38/35. Using the SQL Server Management Studio feature "Edit top 200 rows" on a table, you can enter a number, only to have the cell change to "< Unable to read data >".

If you run a SELECT statement, the value that you entered is shown. But if a C# program calls a Stored Proc to retrieve the value, it reports a numeric overflow.

I really need to store and retrieve and **pass to C#** numbers that are smaller than -800 in a decimal(29, 26) column. Any ideas?

Comment: I would take "edit top 200 rows" out of the equation and write a repro which includes the C# code with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The decimals, which you defined in the Sql Server are bigger then the specification of the C# decimal:

Sql Server:
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments

C#:
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

As you can see, the deinfition of your SQL Server decimal is 17 bytes while the C# decimal only has up to 16 bytes. Therefore, you get an overflow.

**EDIT:**
I have just checked up on the recommended type mappings. From the image display here, a `double` might be working for you. However I have not tested this:
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/sql-clr-type-mapping#type-mapping-run-time-behavior-matrix

Comment: I appreciate the documentation, but it fails to answer my questions. Why can C# receive -790 from a decimal(29, 26) column but not from a decimal(38, 35) column? And why can't C# receive -795 from decimal(29, 26) yet it can receive -790? This can't be about number of bytes.

Comment: Can you provide the C# code that shows this behaviour?

Comment: I cannot affirm that SQL Server Management Studio was written in C#. Maybe it was written in C. But that doesn't matter. The point is, the SSMS feature "Edit Top 200 Rows" will let you input numbers and then tell you "<Unable to read data>", meaning that it cannot display them for editing even though a SELECT statement can retrieve them.

Comment: In C# you find the problem by calling a SQL stored proc and trying to copy the retrieved data into a DataTable:

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
 using (SqlDataReader reader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
 {
  dt.Load(reader);
 }
}

Comment: So your problem does not actually lie with C# but with the 'Edit top 200 Rows' feature of SSMS?

Comment: Look at my previous comment. There is C# code that has the problem. The overflow occurs at dt.load(reader). The workaround will have to be to convert all numbers to text in the Stored Proc, and the text will successfully load into a table, and then before the table is used, the data must be converted back into a decimal that will not overflow. Can anyone think of a better way?